# How to pop multiple views off a navigation stack?

Tags: swiftui, react-navigation-stack

Looking for some guidance on a simple way to pop multiple views off a navigation stack in SwiftUI.
I have 4 views chained together using NavigationLink. At the last view I would like to jump back to the initial ContentView, popping all the other views off the stack.  I don't want to use the "Back" button on the NavigationBar of each view to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.
Bob.
'''

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: BView()) {
                    Text("This is View A, now go to View B.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct BView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: CView()) {
                Text("This is View B, now go to View C.")
        }
    }
}

struct CView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: DView()) {
                Text("This is View C, now go to View D.")
        }
    }
}
struct DView: View {
    var body: some View {
        // The following line adds ContentView onto the existing navigation stack. Instead, I want to pop the previous views off the stack, leaving me back at ContentView.
        NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
            Text("This is View D, now jump back to View A.")
        }
    }
}
```

'''

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not really "popping" views off of the stack, but your `SceneDelegate` can set the `rootViewController` to any View you want (see line 28 of default `SceneDelegate.swift`). In your case you want it to be `ContentView` again.

For example in your `SceneDelegate` add something like:

```
func toContentView() {
    let contentView = ContentView()
    window?.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
  }
```

Then in `DView`, change the `NavigationLink` to a `Button` that just does:

```
(UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.toContentView()
```

If you have multiple scenes, you'll need a bit more.

Comment: Thank you Cenk, that works! I would never have figured that out myself.  I really appreciate the response. Many thanks, Bob.

Comment: Thanks - I have wasted hours looking for this, other solutions either crashed or meant injecting properties all the way through the navigation chain

Answer (score 1):

Making Cenk Bilgen's answer more generic.

```
struct RootView {
static func change(to view: AnyView) {
    guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
      let sceneDelegate = windowScene.delegate as? SceneDelegate else {
      return
    }
    let contentView = view
    sceneDelegate.window?.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
}
```

}

Usage:

```
RootView.change(to: AnyView(DashboardView()))
```