# SwiftUI - Using @main to set the rootViewController

Tags: swiftui, uiscenedelegate

When using the SceneDelegate in SwiftUI, it was possible to create a function like the one below that could be used to set the view [as shown here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59425478/how-to-pop-multiple-views-off-a-navigation-stack) However, in the latest version we now use a WindowsGroup. Is it possible to write a function that changes the view in the WindowsGroup?

```
func toContentView() {
   let contentView = ContentView()
      window?.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63276688/12299030?

Comment: I think it might get the job done, thank you, but I'm really hoping that I can figure this one out in a way that's similar to the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is possible alternate approach that do actually the same as your old `toContentView`

1. helper class

```
class Resetter: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = Resetter()

    @Published private(set) var contentID = UUID()

    func toContentView() {
        contentID = UUID()
    }
}
```

2. content of @main

```
    @StateObject var resetter = Resetter.shared
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
               .id(resetter.contentID)
        }
    }
```

3. now from anywhere in code to reset to `ContentView` you can just call

```
Resetter.shared.toContentView()
```